# DLL injection and create thread error

Tags: multithreading, dll, code-injection

I have some problem with DLL injection and creation thread. So i simply attach my DLL to some process, and in main function of DLL I am trying to create thread. I tried several methods `boost::thread::join()`, `std::thread::join()` (after joining target application hangs), `CreateThread(...)`,`_beginthread()` - my target application is ruining down. 
Please, tell me, why I cannot start thread after injection? (DLL injection is successful, I have this problems after starting a thread)
And is it possible to solve this problem?

Where should I look for?

Platform win32, MSVC++

Comment: I know this is old but take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428881/calling-a-function-in-an-injected-dll for something that might help yout

Answer (score 1):

Don't do anything scary in your `DllMain` as it runs while the loader lock is held. You might get away with calling `CreateThread`, but the thread won't even start until `DllMain` returns.