# Injected DLL not correct HMODULE

Tags: c++, module, loadlibrary, dll-injection

So I am injecting a DLL into a program. I can verify that the DLL is injected with help from Process Explorer. After the injection I am looping all modules from the process, comparing the names and return the injected dll as a HMODULE.

Then I GetProcAddress() this HMODULE to find a extern function inside of it, but for some reason this does not work properly.

```
HMODULE dllAddress = getModuleAddressFromProc(pid, "NewDll.dll");
externCreateThread createThread = (externCreateThread)GetProcAddress(dllAddress, "createThread");
```

When I breakpoint and check dllAddress it says:

[image]

When I use LoadLibrary to load the DLL in my current program and use that as a HMODULE, it does work.

```
HMODULE dllAddress = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\NewDll.dll");
externCreateThread createThread = (externCreateThread)GetProcAddress(dllAddress, "createThread");
```

Breakpointing to check dllAddress:

[image]

The returned HMODULE from the list of HMODULES is not the same as the HMODULE from LoadLibrary. Although the pointer address is the same.

Listing all the modules from the process is done with the code Microsoft provides. I altered it a bit to work with string comparison, but that does not effect the HMODULE type.

```
HMODULE getModuleAddressFromProc(DWORD pid, string moduleName) {
    HMODULE hMods[1024];
    DWORD cbNeeded;
    HMODULE output;
    unsigned int i;
    HANDLE newHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);
    if (EnumProcessModules(newHandle, hMods, sizeof(hMods), &cbNeeded)) {
        for (i = 0; i < (cbNeeded / sizeof(HMODULE)); i++) {
            TCHAR szModName[MAX_PATH];
            if (GetModuleFileNameEx(newHandle, hMods[i], szModName, sizeof(szModName) / sizeof(TCHAR))) {
                string s2 = charToString(szModName);
                if (s2.find(moduleName) != string::npos) {
                    output = hMods[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with help from:

[RectangleEquals](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1500110/rectangleequals) -> [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13447189/616396)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `HMODULE` of a DLL loaded within another process but you cannot use it from your process to get the address of a procedure of that `HMODULE`.

This is due to the fact that each process in Windows has its own memory space. Therefore the `HMODULE` value of the same DLL loaded in different processes is almost certainly different each time. So once you obtained the `HMODULE` of your DLL within another process and call `GetProcAddress(..)` with it, Windows looks within the memory of your application and not within that of the other process. Since the `HMODULE` is invalid in your application `GetProcAddress(..)` will fail.

If you want to call a functions within the context of another process you have to use some sort of [interprocess communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). To do this you have to have a thread running within the other process to handle those IPCs (which I guess `createThread` should do).

To achieve this you can use the `DllMain(..)` function of your injected DLL to execute some code (e.g. call function `createThread(..)`):

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL,  // handle to DLL module
                    DWORD fdwReason,     // reason for calling function
                    LPVOID lpReserved )  // reserved
{

   switch( fdwReason ) 
   { 
      case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
         createThread(..);
         break;

      case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
         // Do thread-specific initialization.
         break;

      case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
         // Do thread-specific cleanup.
         break;

      case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
         // Perform any necessary cleanup.
         break;
   }

   return (TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that initially but it seems you can not create a thread from DllMain as it breaks down the program. Therefore I went looking for a method around it.

Comment: You can create threads from within `DllMain` as stated by the MSDN (and done by me several times). The only difference is that the thread does not start immediately but after loading of the dll is done. Did you try a very simple thread for testing (e.g a while(1) with a MessageBox/MessageBeep every second)?

Comment: I tried a non ending while loop from DllMain, the program that got the DLL injected freezes until the while loop is escaped. I tried CreatThread() and that kills the program.
Edit: DllMain runs while the loader lock is held.