# Calling a function in a remote process with parameters (injected DLL)

Tags: c++, windows, dll, rpc, dll-injection

I've been trying to call a function which resides in an injected `DLL` using the `DLL injector` process. The code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13447189/3764804) answer works fine with no arguments but passing an argument causes random (non-initialized) gibberish like `-1733099520` to be passed to the function instead of the desired `DWORD`:

```
DWORD speed_up = 1;
RemoteLibraryFunction(hProcess, targetDll, "set_speedup", &speed_up, sizeof speed_up, &lpReturn);
```

The `DLL` function I'm calling is defined as:

```
#define DLL_EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

DLL_EXPORT void set_speedup(const DWORD new_speed)
{
    sprintf_s(debug_message_buffer, "Setting new speed to: %i\n", new_speed);
    OutputDebugStringA(debug_message_buffer);
    speed = new_speed;
}
```

Note that I'm using [`DebugView++`](https://github.com/CobaltFusion/DebugViewPP/releases) to observe the output of `OutputDebugStringA()`.

What am I doing wrong? It seems like the parameters are not set/passed correctly but the code seems correct and no functions failed.

Comment: Attach a debugger to the remote process. When execution reaches `set_speedup`, go up one stack frame and see how the parameters were set up. Compare that against the function preamble to see how it expects its parameters.

Comment: What is the calling convention? Enforce it perhaps with __stdcall.

Comment: `CreateRemoteThread` expects the `ThreadProc` to use WINAPI __stdcall calling conventions, while the default calling convention is __cdecl. This should be evident from the disassembly in my first comment.

Comment: @Botje: Thanks for the calling conventions hint but enforcing `__stdcall` still does not work. It now yields values like `528154624`: `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall set_speedup(const DWORD new_speed)`

Comment: Back to the debugger then. That will tell you how arguments are passed and how the function expects them.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the passed parameter was passed in as address of the `DWORD` instead of the `DWORD`. This can be fixed by changing the called function's signature to something like the following:

```
#define DLL_EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

DLL_EXPORT void set_speedup(const LPVOID acceleration_pointer)
{
    const auto acceleration = *static_cast<DWORD*>(acceleration_pointer);
    speed = acceleration;
}
```

The calling convention did not matter. Now the call works as expected.